# save image with overlay in the camera view

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios5

I have added a overlay over the camera view using the below code,

```
- (IBAction)takephoto:(id)sender {

    mediaPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    mediaPicker.delegate=self;
    mediaPicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    mediaPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    // overlay on top of camera lens view
    UIImageView *cameraOverlayView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Overlay2.png"]];
    cameraOverlayView.alpha = 0.0f;
    mediaPicker.cameraOverlayView = cameraOverlayView;

    // animate the fade in after the shutter opens
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:2.2f];
    cameraOverlayView.alpha = 1.0f;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [self presentViewController:mediaPicker animated:YES completion:Nil];

}
```

How to save the captured image with overlay image in it? That is I need to save both the captured image and overlay as a single image.

Comment: I am not sure that how to save image with overlay. But one thing that you can do for this problem is   "After saving image taken from camera, get that image and merge this image with overlay image using aplha property with overlay image. You can get captured image with overlay"

Answer (score 0):

I had done something like this , What you do is take a `UIView` which would act as a container view and now add two I mage view to It such as I have done in code below. Create Container View and add two ImageView so that It looks Like below in your storyBoard

[image]

now just use this code

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(
    containerView.bounds.size, 
    view.opaque,
    0.0
);

[containerView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return img;
```

This img which you would get, is the combined Image of the two ImageViews

Answer (score 0):

```
        imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imgPicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    imgPicker.delegate   = self;
    imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imgPicker.showsCameraControls=NO;
    imgPicker.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
    imgPicker.edgesForExtendedLayout = YES;
    imgPicker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto;
    imgPicker.cameraCaptureMode=UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;

    imgPicker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(imgPicker.cameraViewTransform, CAMERA_TRANSFORMWidth , CAMERA_TRANSFORM);


    UIView* overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:imgPicker.view.frame];
    CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 25.0);
    imgPicker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(translate, CAMERA_TRANSFORM, CAMERA_TRANSFORM);
    imgPicker.cameraOverlayView = overlayView;



    UIImageView *stripImageVW=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,self.view.frame.size.height-70,self.view.frame.size.width,70)];

    [stripImageVW setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Black_StripView"]];
    [overlayView addSubview:stripImageVW];
```